# No se añade un nuevo objeto a un array en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, javascript-objeto, funcion

En este algoritmo la idea sería usarlo para añadir un nuevo objeto a un array pero en este caso no lo hace y no entiendo por qué... ¿quizás esté mal planteada la función?

```
class Persona {
  constructor(idUsuario, nombre, apellido, edad, DNI) {
      this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
      this.nombre = nombre.toUpperCase();
      this.apellido = apellido.toUpperCase();
      this.edad = edad;
      this.DNI = DNI;
  }

  nombreCompleto() {
      this.nombre = this.nombre + " " + this.apellido;
  }
}

function agregarPersona() { 
  cantUsuarios++; //Sumo 1 a la variable que cuenta la cant de usuarios ingresados.
  arrayUsuarios = []
  arrayUsuarios.push( //pusheo un nuevo objeto "Persona" para ser agregado a arrayUsuarios
      new Persona(
          cantUsuarios, //defino al idUsuario (primer dato de la clase) utilizando la cantidad de usuarios, si este es el primero su id será 1.
          prompt("Ingrese Su Nombre: "), //pido dato "nombre"
          prompt("Ingrese su Apellido: "), //pido dato "apellido"
          prompt("Ingrese su Edad, debe ser sólo el número: "), //pido dato "edad"
          prompt("Ingrese su DNI, debe ser sólo el número: ") //pido dato "DNI"
      )
  ) 

  console.log("Usuario Ingresado: " + arrayUsuarios.find(usuario => usuario.idUsuario === cantUsuarios)); //Acá está el problema! El log me muestra [object Object] en vez de lo que pido
}
```

Comment: Donde estas declarando el arreglo de `arrayUsuarios`?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estas trantando de hacer un log de un objeto y por eso te muestra `[object Object]`. Podrias usar algo asi para ver el contenido del objeto como un string: `JSON.stringify(tuObjeto)`

Comment: ya actualicé el código donde declaro el arrayUsuarios @SamuelSobalvarro y es en la función

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Respuesta

Es porque **estás intentando meter en un string un objeto al concatenarlo**, es por ello que en estás situaciones Javascript te inserta [object Object] dentro del string que se ha dado como resultado.

Si pruebas a ejecutar:

```
console.log(arrayUsuarios.find(usuario => usuario.idUsuario === cantUsuarios));
```

Verás que ahora si te carga el objeto en la consola.

## Tips adicionales

Si necesitas convertir un objeto a string tienes a tu disposición la librería JSON de forma nativa, así que tan solo tienes que ejecutar lo siguiente:

```
JSON.stringify(object);
```

Esto retorna un string que contiene dentro toda la información del objeto, puedes ver el resultado ejecutando:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
```